# 'auth()' is unavailable : use object construction 'FIRAuth()'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get:

> 'auth()' is unavailable : use object construction 'FIRAuth()'

I have added `pod 'Firebase/Auth'` in pod file and execute pod install.

```
FIRAuth.auth().signInWithEmail("essammohamedomran@gmail.com", password: "rootroot") {(user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
        print(user?.email);
    }
    else
    {
        print(error?.description);
    }
}
```

However when i used project that already have needed frameworks installed on it like 'Firebase/Auth', the same code worked with me !

Is it problem with my installed cocoapods ?

**UPDATE :**

Finally, i discovered that it was Xcode version problem .. i have updated my Xcode v7.2 to Xcode v8.2 and my problem is solved.

thanks everyone,

Comment: If you are using the most current version of Firebase (4.x) then FIRAuth is no longer used, it is Auth(). However, if you are using Firebase 3, then FIRAuth is correct. As you can see, there's not enough information in the question to propose an accurate answer. More importantly, either way, *FIRAuth.auth().signInWithEmail* is not valid. It's *Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail:...*. Please see [Sign in a user with an email address and password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth)

Answer (score 1):

Change FIRAuth.auth() to Auth.auth(). The latest version of Firebase uses Auth for authorizations instead.

Comment: i have tried this solution before but it doesn't work with me !

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from signing in through the app delegate. Instead, create a button in your initial view controller and add an action that signs in a user. I don't think the scope in App Delegate would recognize Auth since it is still being configured.

Comment: If you send me your code, I could debug it and show you your error.

Comment: thanks so much, i can write the appDelegate code here which in the error occurs or i can send you the project to see pod file and other files .. it's simple because i didn't write any more codes.

Comment: Send me the project at 'theheibergproject@gmail.com'